# Theta forecast algorithm producing ridiculously high forecasts

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm currently using multiple algorithms to forecast a time series with intermittent history in R, of which theta algorithm is one. I'm using the `thetaf` function in R. Have attached the code below:

```
a <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31,1682.19888717173,1682.19888717173,138.046666666667,286,192.716666666667,0.9,0.206666666666667,0,0,0,0,96,1774.94938783069,1671.25,141.3,196,25,0.0466666666666667,9.02666666666667,3.08666666666667,6,1.06,1,1.34666666666667,1862.04,1922.55311169419,18,267,22,44,761.11,29,13,1129.67333333333,119.586666666667,34,1429,1284.22333333333);
flag <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
b <- as.data.frame(a)
b$Flag=flag
c <- subset(b,cumsum(b$Flag)==1)
c <- subset(c,cumsum(c$a)>0)
d <- ts(c$a, frequency = 12)
ThetaF <- thetaf(d, h = 24)$mean
```

The forecasts that the model produces are extremely high for the months of November and December. History has high data points in the months of Nov and Dec(around 1.5K) but the forecasts are nowhere near, they are upwards of 400K for Nov and Dec. Would appreciate help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the theta method works for seasonal data like this.

```r
library(forecast)
n <- length(d)
# Decompose series
decomp <- decompose(d, type = "multiplicative")
# Compute seasonally adjusted data
x <- seasadj(decomp)
# Fit SES model
fcast <- ses(x, h = 24)
alpha <- fcast$model$par["alpha"]
# Fit linear trend model
fit <- lm(x ~ seq_along(x))
beta <- coefficients(fit)[2]
# Add drift term to SES model
theta_fcast <- fcast$mean + beta / 2 * (0:23 + (1 - (1 - alpha)^n) / alpha)
# Re-seasonalize the forecasts
theta_fcast <- theta_fcast * rep(tail(decomp$seasonal, 12), 2)
```

Let's check what happens with this particular series. First, look at the decomposition.

```
# Check decomposition
autoplot(decomp)
```

[image]

Notice the very large variation in values of the seasonal component (above 5 in Feb/March, but close to zero in several other months).

```r
# Check SES model
autoplot(fcast, PI = FALSE)
```

[image]

The seasonal component is applied to the seasonally adjusted data. Because of the strange seasonal component, the seasonally adjusted data has a weird jump in the last year which is inflating the forecasts. The weird jump is also inflating the slope of the fitted trend line to the same data, so that makes the seasonally adjusted forecasts even worse. Then you reseasonalize the results, and you get this.

```r
# Plot adjusted forecasts
autoplot(d) + autolayer(theta_fcast, color="blue")
```

[image]

The bottom line is that the theta method is not particularly robust to extreme seasonal patterns. You would be better off with a different model family. Here's an example using an ETS model which works pretty well for this data set.

```r
# A better model
ets_fcast <- ets(d) |> forecast(h = 24)
autoplot(ets_fcast, PI = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>